# Merging two wp_posts tables while avoiding duplicates

Tags: database, duplicates

Is there a simple way to merge two wp_posts tables while avoiding duplicates?

Comment: Short answer: "Yes, that is possible." For an answer that also answers the implied "How?" you will need to supply more information. Where is the second table right now (in a file, in the same DB under a different name)? How do you plan on identifying "duplicates"?

Comment: The second DB is in a .sql file. I plan to identify duplicates with the 'post_content' field.

Answer (score 1):

Import the new table as `wp_posts_2`, then join them and delete all duplicates based on post_content; then merge the two tables.

The following SQL query (untested!) should give the posts from the new table to be deleted:

```
SELECT wp2.* FROM wp_posts_2 as wp2 LEFT JOIN wp_posts as wp ON wp2.post_content = wp.post_content WHERE wp2.post_content = wp.post_content
```

So, you can delete the entries with this query (also untested):

```
DELETE wp_posts_2.* LEFT JOIN wp_posts as wp ON wp_posts_2.post_content = wp.post_content WHERE wp_posts_2.post_content = wp.post_content
```

Then merge the two tables.